# QT 5.6.1 Designer x64 not launching

Tags: c++, windows, qt, 64-bit, qt-designer

I installed **QT 5.6.1 x64** toolset (using qt-opensource-windows-x86-msvc2015_64-5.6.1-1 setup file) on the PC using Windows 10 Pro x64. It seems to QT Designer (.../bin/designer.exe) is not starting. It is in task manager process list (with 0% CPU and 12 MB memory using) but nothing is shown (no windows, splashes etc).

QT Designer from **QT 5.1.1 x86** toolset works properly.

Should I need QT 5.6.1 **x86** toolset to use QT Designer tool? Or there is another way?

The same problem is using QT 5.7 x64

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yeah, I just deleted (move to another directory works too :) ):

- Qt5WebEngineWidgets.dll.
- Qt5WebEngineWidgetsd.dll
- Qt5WebEngineWidgetsd.pdb

And QT Designer starts and works fine.

Sure, it's a temporary solution. Bug had been reported before. Will wait for solution.

Comment: I have also find the bug report, but this work around doesn't work for me... I still cannot run the designer.exe

Answer (score 3):

I have run in to the same issue. After some searching I found that it's a bug that is still open: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-53984

The bug report mentions to "remove" Qt5WebEngineWidgets.dll. Doing so seemed to fix it for me, but obviously it's a good idea to keep an eye on this bug report for when it gets fixed.